# Geoserver - Set URL (local path) of a new ImageMosaic created by Geoserver REST API

Tags: python, rest, curl, geoserver

I'm trying to automate the generation process of an ImageMosaic in Geoserver using its REST API.
If I set all the requested parameters (name, URL = local path in the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR) by the Geoserver administration web pages the creation process is correctly performed and the referenced URL is (as specificied):

> [GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR]/data/[ThematicDomainName]/[workspace]/raster/myImageMosaic

If I try to do the same task using the GEOSERVER REST API (either via cURL or using the python lib *gsconfig*) the best (without errors) result that I'm able to obtain is the generation of the following directories structure:

> [GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR]/data/[workspace]/myImageMosaic

...that is quite different from what I need!

**Is there any parameter to set (or process to follow) for changing the default URL (path) in the ImageMosaic generation process via Geoserver REST API?**

I already had a look and tested the istructions provided in the following links:

- Geoserver official documentation [creating-an-empty-mosaic-and-harvest-granules](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#creating-an-empty-mosaic-and-harvest-granules)
- gsconfig GitHub page [GitHub - gsconfig](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig)
- GeoSolution training web page - gsconfig

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried requesting the REST resource for the mosaic you created using the GUI to see how it's set in there?